# How to keep the phone screen on while charging?

Tags: screen, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g3

I have Moto G gen 3 updated to latest system update, not rooted.

I need a simple solution to keep my phone's screen awake when it's plugged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a checkbox exactly for that in the developer options, you'll just have to enable them to show up.

To do so, locate the about/version information in the Settings app and tap the build number repeatedly until you get the confirmation.

Then go back and look for the Developer Settings. Make sure to not touch any option you don't understand. Wrong values might make your device unresponsive or unusable, they could also compromise your data's security.

Comment: @Mario how can I revert back the developer setting that I unlocked? If I revert it will the settings that I changed also will get reverted?

Comment: You simply have to do a Factory Restore to hide developer options again.Yes, once you do factory reset all settings will revert back to Normal.

Comment: Factory reset also erases everything on your phone.  That's not really a solution for how to *just* hide the developer settings again.